# FInd the limit without the l’Hospital’s rule

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

FInd the limit without the l’Hospital’s rule:

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}{\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+2}}$$

I have tried multiplying the equation with:

$\frac{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x+2}}{\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x+2}}$ and got stuck with 
$\frac{(3-\sqrt{x^2+5})(\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+2})}{2x-(x+2)}$ 
$\implies$ $\frac{(3-\sqrt{x^2+5})(\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+2})}{x-2}$

$\frac{3+\sqrt{x^2+5}}{3+\sqrt{x^2+5}}$ and got stuck with 
$\frac{3^2-(x^2+5)}{(\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+2})(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}$ 
$\implies$ $\frac{14-x^2}{(\sqrt{2x}-\sqrt{x+2})(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}$

I tried to solve the denominator in the second one (which is the same as the nominator in the first but with different signs) which ended up with: 
$\frac{14-x^2}{3\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{2x(x^2+5)}-3\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{(x+2)(x^2+5)}}$

What can I do after that?

The answer with the l’Hospital’s rule (using [Symbolab](http://symbolab.com)) $-\frac{8}{3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made some errors in arithmetic.  The solution involves doing **both** of the things you tried:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}{\sqrt{2x} - \sqrt{x+2}} &= \frac{(3^2 - (x^2+5))( \sqrt{2x} + \sqrt{x+2})}{(2x - (x+2))(3 + \sqrt{x^2+5})} \\ &= \frac{(4-x^2)(\sqrt{2x} + \sqrt{x+2})}{(x-2)(3 + \sqrt{x^2+5})} \\
&= -(x+2) \frac{\sqrt{2x} + \sqrt{x+2}}{3 + \sqrt{x^2+5}}. \end{align*}$$  Now all expressions are nonzero when $x = 2$, giving $$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{3-\sqrt{x^2+5}}{\sqrt{2x} - \sqrt{x+2}} = -(2+2) \frac{\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{4}}{3 + \sqrt{9}} = -\frac{8}{3}.$$

As you can see, the reason why you need to do both is because there is a factor of $x-2$ that appears in both the numerator and denominator, and this is what needs to cancel out in order for the limit to be computed.  You did each method by itself but without doing both, that factor cannot be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is correct, but there a sign error in the numerator of your first fraction. Doing what you were, it should have been:

$$=\frac{(3-\sqrt{x^2+5})(\sqrt{2x}\color{red}+\sqrt{x+2})}{2x-(x+2)}$$
$$=\frac{(3-\sqrt{x^2+5})(\sqrt{2x}+\sqrt{x+2})}{2x-(x+2)}\cdot\color{blue}{\frac{(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}{(3+\sqrt{x^2+5})}}$$

You can do it fairly easily now...